# pass variable to webpack to build different bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am trying to build a different bundle based on an argument passed to webpack.

I have a `create-react-app` that I have ejected from and currently currently if I do `npm run build` it builds a bundle using webpack. As I have both an english and spanish version of the site I was hoping that I could pass an argument here. i.e. to build a Spanish version something like `npm run build:es`.

My webpack file currently just builds the English bundle. There is a separate process during the application to pull in translations, but during the building of the bundle it would be great if I could stipulate which language to build the bundle for.

Anyone have any ideas.

The relevant webpack code is below:

```
//default messages for translations
var defaultMessages = require('/translations/en.json');

//more webpack stuff......

{
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    loader: require.resolve('string-replace-loader'),
    query: {
          multiple: Object.keys(defaultMessages).map(key => ({
           search: `__${key}__`,
           replace: defaultMessages[key]
          }))
    }
},
```

Comment: You could set different environment variables and import based on that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox I'm not sure, that's why I am asking the question :-)

Comment: (that's why I commented, not answered)

Comment: @evolutionxbox i know man, I appreciate it :-) just a bit stuck with this one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Webpack can receive a `--env` argument, which is then passed to the `webpack.config` file. The key is to export a function returning the configuration from your `webpack.config.js`, not the raw configuration.

```
$ webpack --env=lang_es
```

And in `webpack.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function(env) {
  if (env === 'lang_es') {
    // ...
  }
  return {
    module: {
      // ...
    },
    entry: {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

And in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "build_es": "webpack --env=lang_es",
}
```

This was originally really meant to distinguish between build types, e.g. development or production, but it's just a string passed into the config file - you can give it any meaning you want.

As hinted in the comments, using environment variables is the second, webpack-independent, approach. You can set the environment variable directly in `package.json`'s scripts section:

```
"scripts": {
  "build_es": "BUILD_LANG=es webpack",
}
```

(Use [`cross-env`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) to set the environment when developing on Windows).

And in `webpack.config.js`:

```
if (process.env.BUILD_LANG === 'es') {
  // ...
}
```

This environment-based approach has been used in a few places already (for example Babel's `BABEL_ENV` variable), so I'd say that it has gathered enough mileage to consider it proven and tested.

**Edit: fixed the cross-env part to mention that it's only necessary on Windows.**

Comment: hey @stefan. in my `package.json` my `build:prod` command looks like this:`build:prod: APP_ENV=production npm run build `. If I want to extend this should it be `build_es: APP_ENV=production npm run build cross-env BUILD_LANG=es webpack`? I have tried this but it doesn't seem to work, quite possibly because of the `APP_ENV` and `cross-env`

Comment: You don't actually need cross-env, unless you're developing on Windows (should have mentioned that). It should be `APP_ENV=production BUILD_LANG=es webpack`

Comment: thanks! does that mean I can also drop `npm run build`?

Comment: If it just runs webpack, sure. But it doesn't hurt to run `npm run build`.

Comment: `process.env.BUILD_LANG` gets picked up as undefined is the only thing

Comment: `"build": "APP_ENV=production BUILD_LANG=es webpack"` works for me - `BUILD_LANG` gets picked up as `'es'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149580/discussion-between-raul-rodriguez-and-stefan-dragnev).